# "**** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module" when installing ruby-filemagic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle

I needed gem ruby-filemagic for some requirements in my project. I included it in my Gemfile and when i ran bundle install its giving me this error

```
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install [libmagic](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/libdevel/libmagic-dev) for that to work, since that is the underlying library it uses.  The actual instructions will vary from distro to distro, so you'll need to give us more information about your OS if you need help installing libmagic itself.

Comment: its Ubuntu 12.04 and i have libmagic1 already installed...tell me if I have to do anything more.